# Разрешены ли на сайте вопросы, связанные в проверкой кода?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Предположим, что человек написал работающую программу. Ему не нужно задавать вопросы с просьбой починки кода,исправления ошибок и тому подобного, но он понимает, что его код не идеален, требует грамотного рефакторинга и вообще может работать быстрее. Можно ли, и если да, то в каком формате, задавать вопросы с просьбой проверки кода, с целью тыканья носом в участки кода, которые необходимо подредактировать, чтобы все работало лучше?

Comment: Я понял, а что теперь с этим дубликатом делать? Удалять?

Comment: Не, оставьте. Механизм дубликатов нужен для сохранения разных вариаций проблемы с совпадающими решениями.

Comment: @D-side как скажете